# net 8 error to upgrade dependency of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel

Tags: .net-8.0

After migrating a web api project from net 6 to 8, it throws this runtime error on startup. it compiles with no errors.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

I just changed 6 to 8 in the properties window for target framework.

However, I noticed this thing that I don't understand, the DWA.Framework library references Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel (8.0.0)

[image: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel (8.0.0)]

Instead, in the Host DWA.API project that references DWA.Framework, the same library is present in version 5.0.0

[image: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel (5.0.0)]

What do I have to do so that the reference is updated to 8?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the package in question and reapplied? I have seen the issue in some occassions

Comment: Yes I did, no changes